# How can I force a redirect_to to redirect only after Active Record updates the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I update a user in Rails app and update a record, I often have to press the submit button twice to redirect to page that I want.  The first time I submit the button, the page seems to redirect to the edit page again, but then the flash message does not show up.  When all the records are full, it is supposed to redirect to the show page, but only does that after the second click.  I also have an `@asset = @user.asset.update_attributes()` earlier in the controller action.

Below is my code:

```
def update
    @user.update(user_params)
    if @user.asset
      @asset = @user.asset.update_attributes(:asset_one_type => Asset::IMAGE)
    else      
      @asset = @user.create_asset(:asset_one_type => Asset::IMAGE)
    end
    @incompleteArray = formFinished @user

    if @incompleteArray.length > 0
      @incomplete = true 
    else
      @incomplete = false
    end


    if @incompleteArray.length == 0
      p 'its doing this'
      redirect_to action: 'show'
    else
      p 'its doing that else'
      flash.now[:notice] = 'Please fill out the required fields.'
      redirect_to action: 'edit' , incomplete: @incomplete
    end

  end
```

Comment: Paste the full controller method to see where variables are coming from.

Comment: @JorgedelosSantos I just posted the full controller method.  Based on the puts testing that I did it the if statement works as intended, but it's just not redirecting to what it should be.  It seems as though the page just refreshes, but somehow still records the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this, you might need to check if the update succeded before doing anything else. And if it works you still have two options. That the incompleteArray is empty or not.

```
  def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      if @user.asset
        @asset = @user.asset.update_attributes(:asset_one_type => Asset::IMAGE)
      else
        @asset = @user.create_asset(:asset_one_type => Asset::IMAGE)
      end
      incompleteArray = formFinished @user # What does this do?

      incomplete = incompleteArray.length > 0

      if @incompleteArray.length == 0
        p 'its doing this'
        redirect_to action: 'show'
      else
        p 'its doing that else'
        flash.now[:notice] = 'Please fill out the required fields.'
        redirect_to action: 'edit' , incomplete: incomplete
      end
    else
      #whatever happens when @user.update fails
    end
  end
```

Also don't use this many @variables if you are not using them in the view.

Comment: @user.update might not work because of the validations, but you won't notice because you are not handling the exception. As .save returns false if it fails, you have to do an if else statement to check for it and act according to this.